# How to print the inserted/filled text of the pdf and not the entire pdf form?

Tags: pdf, printing, forms

Ok maybe I wasn't able to describe my question properly. I'll try my best to elaborate further.

I scanned an actual form and will be using it as a "guide only" for our users/staffs. I would like to ask if it's possible to only print the "typed entries" and not the entire pdf form for it will be print in a physical form sheet?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the PDF viewer you use. Adobe Acrobat/Reader has an option in the print dialog which prints only Annotations (which means form fields, comments etc.).

A little caveat: you may have to fiddle a bit with the settings and even add some "marker fields" to make sure that the output matches.